# What is this set of claw-levers and bolts?

Tags: hand-tools

This has been in my garage for a while, but I have no ideas what it is.
Anyone out there know?[image: ""]

Answer (score 51):

It is a gear puller. A two and and three arm, use to pull gears/bearings off off shafts/holes.  Use the bolts to connect a pair of flats to the centre piece to the arms.  The long screw goes in the centre hole, place it against centre of a shaft, the arms go to outside of gear and you turn the screw to remove gear from shaft.

Comment: Most certainly a gear-pulling set. I have a set that looks almost identical to that.

Comment: Indeed a gear puller, but often not the best one to use.  A "harmonic balancer" type works better in most cases, such as flywheel removal.  It uses bolts to make a positive connection.  The arms on the type shown above can slip off easily, or even break.  However, it does work well for things like removing boat steering wheels.

Comment: @Jason  Quite a few different types.  Each type has best design use/size.  Type above usually best for accessible gears without drilled/tapped holes.

Comment: What's it look like when assembled? I'm trying to picture it in my head from your description and not getting anything coherent.

Comment: @nick012000 Just do an image search for "gear puller" and you'll get thousands of pictures: https://images.app.goo.gl/H5j4f3mXekcC7mnu5

Comment: It's the sort of tool for which you cannot find a good substitute.  So if you ever potentially want to pull something off a shaft without twisting or hammering, this is the tool.   Can you tell I've needed one and not had one?

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted.